# How do I use nvm with c-shell?

Tags: node.js, csh, nvm

I'm new to javascript development and am trying to update my NodeJS version for the tutorial that I'm following. All the directions I can find on the web say to use nvm to update the version. I installed nvm and used it to download/install an updated version of NodeJS. However, I can only find .sh files and it modified only .bashrc.

The documentation page says it supports any POSIX-compliant shell, which I think csh is. There is no explicit mention of csh, which I find odd since it's one of the most popular shells (albeit, not well regarded). Strangely, I also can't find any references on Google when I search for "nvm csh".

Can I use nvm with c-shell and, if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but `csh` is NOT a POSIX compliant shell. If you want a shell that 'feels' like `csh` but has better parsing etc. and can be POSIX compliant, I suggest `zsh`.